# C language returns wrong answer when using remainder

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    printf("Enter the change amount in Dollars: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b = a % 50;
    printf("Number of 100 Dollar bills = %d \n", b);
    c = a % 10;
    printf("Number of 50 Dollar bills = %d \n", c);
    d = a % 5;
    printf("Number of 20 Dollar bills = %d \n", d);
    e = a % 1;
    printf("Number of 1 Dollar bills = %d \n", e);
    return(0);
}
```

It returns a wrong answer. How to fix this issue?

..............................................................................

Comment: *wrong answer* What does that mean? What do you get and what would you expect?

Comment: Why would you *expect* `a % 50` to give you the number of 100 bills? (What do you think `a % 50` means?)

Comment: Everything is OK with the remainder function. Your application logic is wrong. (as ruakh pointed out ... and the same issue with the followup code).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would recommend, to try to find a valid algorithm on pen and paper first and than code it.

Comment: i mean, if i entered "128" in 50 dollars ,for example, i would get 2. But instead i get 28!

Comment: And how many dollar bills will `a % 1` be?

Comment: You don't need the remainder, you need the quotient: 128 / 50 = 2 bills. 128 % 50 =28 .The remainder. What you are left with.

Comment: The answer it would be: 0

Comment: Thank you all for your help, especially Weather Vane.

Comment: `return` is not a function.

Comment: The remainder operator gives you the **remainder** of the division, so `128 % 50` -> `100 / 2 == 2` is and integer so the remainder `28`. @Juergen there is no such thing as a remainder function `%` is an operator.

Comment: @iharob: Sorry for being not precise enough.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_easing in progress during program execution?

Answer (score 2):

## Take a look at [Modulus Operand in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

Here's what's wrong with the program:
Let's look at this calculation: `b = a % 50;`
This gives us: `100 % 50 = 0;` (if we say the input is 100).
And when you try to take modulus of b what happens is this: `c = b % 10;`
This will leave you with `0 % 10 = 0`
You're trying to find out what the remainder of 100 divided by 50 is, which is zero.

To solve this (Using your assignment):
Step 1. Divide input by the amount of 100 (representing 100 dollar bills).
Step 2. Now take modulus of your input and the amount of 100 - and then divide it by the amount of 50 (representing 50 dollar bills).

Here's an example for better understanding:
Let's say the amount you want change from is 285, then:
`285 / 100 = 2` (This should be 2.85, but since you're using integers you can't represent decimals)

Next up:
`285 / 100 = 2`
`285 % 100 / 50 = 1`
`285 % 100 % 50 / 20 = 1`
`285 % 100 % 50 % 20 / 1 = 15`

`<start value> % <previous compare value> / <newest compare value>`

This results in:
100 dollar bills: 2
50 dollar bills: 1
20 dollar bills: 1
1 dollar bills: 15
Which amounts to 285 dollars.

## Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(){     
int a, b, c, d, e;      

printf("Enter the change amount in Dollars: ");    
scanf("%d", &a);      

b = a/100;      
c = (a%100)/50;     
d = (a%100%50)/20;     
e = (a%100%50%20)/1;       

printf("Number of 100 Dollar bills = %d \n", b);    
printf("Number of 50 Dollar bills = %d \n", c);    
printf("Number of 20 Dollar bills = %d \n", d);    
printf("Number of 1 Dollar bills = %d \n", e);    

return(0);     
}
```

## Tips:

Arrange your C code in a good manner, if you're starting with C and want to have other people help you or collaborate with other programmers you should improve the way you set up your commands.
Take a look at the Solution i posted and see how i separated the calculations and print functions. This will help readability and set you on a path to do good programming!
If posting on Stackoverflow.com please try to use as much time as possible to explain your problem and preferably your code and it's purpose!